# How can I pass RTS options to runghc?

Tags: haskell, ghc

For `ghci`, I can limit the memory ghci can use by

```
$ ghci +RTS -M10m -RTS
```

When I compile the whole program, I can

```
$ ghc -rtsopts a.hs
```

then

```
$ ./a +RTS -M10m
```

How can I do this for `runghc a.hs`? I've tried several ways, like `runghc a.hs +RTS -M10m` , but none of them seem to work. The only option I could limit the memory was by

```
$ export GHCRTS='-M10m'
$ runghc a.hs
```

, but I want this to be one time only, so I prefer doing this by passing arguments to `runghc`.

---

Edit : I'm checking whether the option is working or not using the following strategy (just because I don't know better ways):

```
-- a.hs
f x = f (f x)
main = print $ seq (f 0) 0
```

Open two terminals, one for `top` command and another for executing the code. If the execution stops saying "Heap exhausted", I conclude that `-M[number]m` is working. If the execution continues and uses huge amount of memory, I kill the process and conclude that it didn't succeed.

Comment: `runghc +RTS -M10m a.hs` or `runghc -rtsopts a.hs +RTS -M10m`? (Just guessing)

Comment: @Dogbert Tried both, and neither worked. Thanks anyway :(

Comment: If everything fails, bash allows to set variables "one time only' by using `GHCRTS="-M10m" runghc a.hs` on a single line. This will not set the variable for the next bash commands.

Comment: Have you tried `runghc +RTS -M10m -RTS a.hs` ?

Comment: `runghc +RTS -M10m -RTS a.hs` didn't work either. "one time only" option is nice, thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `GHCRTS=... runghc ...` as [chi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3234959/chi) says is the only way. Because of the way `runghc` interprets its command line, `+RTS` is interpreted as RTS options to `runghc` itself (if it's at the end) or as a program name (if it's at the beginning). It never reaches the runtime. You can force it to be passed to the program using `--RTS +RTS ...` but then it's treated as a program argument and it's still not seen by the runtime.

To investigate this, I wrote a wrapper shell script for `ghc` that traces its arguments, and passed this to `runghc` with the `-f` option.

Create a file `ghc-wrapper` containing:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -x
exec ghc "$@"
```

The `-x` option tells `/bin/sh` to trace every line. Use this with `runghc`:

```sh
$ runghc -f ./ghc-wrapper Hello.hs
+ exec ghc -ignore-dot-ghci -x hs -e :set prog "Hello.hs" -e :main [] Hello.hs
Hello, World!

$ runghc -f ./ghc-wrapper Hello.hs +RTS -s
+ exec ghc -ignore-dot-ghci -x hs -e :set prog "Hello.hs" -e :main [] Hello.hs
Hello, World!
    114,016 bytes allocated in the heap # runghc's heap, not Hello's
    ...

$ runghc -f ./ghc-wrapper Hello.hs --RTS +RTS -s
+ exec ghc -ignore-dot-ghci -x hs -e :set prog "Hello.hs" -e :main ["+RTS","-s"] Hello.hs
Hello, World!

$ runghc -f ./ghc-wrapper -- +RTS -s -RTS Hello.hs
+ exec ghc -ignore-dot-ghci -e :set prog "+RTS" -e :main ["-s","-RTS","Hello.hs"] +RTS
+RTS:1:55:
    Not in scope: `main'
    Perhaps you meant `min' (imported from Prelude)
```

What we really want `runghc` to execute is:

```sh
$ ghc -ignore-dot-ghci -x hs +RTS -s -RTS -e ':set prog "Hello.hs"' -e ':main []' Hello.hs
Hello, World!
      80,654,256 bytes allocated in the heap
      ...
```

But there's no way to specify that because `runghc` doesn't treat `+RTS` specially.